# Webapp requiring additional jars (eg webservices-rt.jar) works in jetty 6 but not 7

Tags: web-services, jar, classpath, jetty

I have a really simple web service which works fine in jetty 6:

```
java -Djetty.class.path=/path/to/webservices-rt.jar -jar start.jar
```

but the same commandline for jetty 7 fails with a `ClassNotFoundException` for `WSServlet`. I also tried adding the jar to `lib/ext` but that didn't work either.

I've tried an example "hello world" app (also requiring webservices-rt.jar) and it exhibits the same behaviour.

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on v7 yet, has anyone else come across this and found a solution?

Comment: Jetty 7 is a pain... Jetty 6, I'll miss you.

Comment: Is it really that bad? I've not used jetty for a while and just grabbed the latest. It's a very simple webapp that will probably never change, but it *will* have to last.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, found the answer. Although it's not mentioned in the documentation for porting/upgrading to jetty 7, there is a minor mention [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Dependencies#External_Dependencies) that the syntax has changed and the new commandline should be:

```
java -jar start.jar lib=/path/to
```

(Note it's the parent path of the jar file above)